# How to get Spring to use WildFly, rather than Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I am trying to implement JSR annotations to handle caching. After a lot of research and several questions on SO I got to the point below. When I try to run this however it says

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer"}}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

HelloService.java

```
@Path("/helloservice")
@EnableCaching
public class HelloService extends CachingSetup{

    @GET
    @Path("/unsecured")
    @Produces({"text/plain"})
    @CacheResult
    public String testUnsecured(){
        return "Unsecured user";
    }
}
```

CachingSetup.java

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;
import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration;
import javax.cache.expiry.Duration;
import javax.cache.expiry.TouchedExpiryPolicy;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheManagerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

  @Component
  public class CachingSetup implements JCacheManagerCustomizer
  {
    @Override
    public void customize(CacheManager cacheManager)
    {
      cacheManager.createCache("basicCache", new MutableConfiguration<>()  
        .setExpiryPolicyFactory(TouchedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(SECONDS, 10))) 
        .setStoreByValue(false)
        .setStatisticsEnabled(true));
    }
  }
```

ehcache.xml

```
<config
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'  
    xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'>  

  <service>
    <jsr107:defaults>
      <jsr107:cache name="basicCache" template="heap-cache"/> 
    </jsr107:defaults>
  </service>

  <cache-template name="heap-cache">
    <listeners>    
      <listener>
        <class>org.terracotta.ehcache.EventLogger</class>
        <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
        <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
        <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on> 
        <events-to-fire-on>UPDATED</events-to-fire-on> 
        <events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on> 
        <events-to-fire-on>REMOVED</events-to-fire-on> 
        <events-to-fire-on>EVICTED</events-to-fire-on> 
      </listener>
    </listeners>
    <resources>
      <heap unit="entries">2000</heap> 
      <offheap unit="MB">100</offheap> 
    </resources>
  </cache-template>
</config>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sentiment360</groupId>
    <artifactId>QuteeDemoRest</artifactId>
    <version>v1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>QuteeDemoRest</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

        <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
      <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.14.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-links -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-links</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxb-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency>        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ehcache/ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
          <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                      <!--SPRING-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Did you see https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications ?

Comment: thanks for the link- im deep into researching it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link from @R.C. above I discovered that I needed to modify my pom.xml to remove the default Spring tomcat implementation

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

needed to be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 

<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I also added

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

right below the version tag at the top making it look like:

```
<groupId>com.sentiment360</groupId>
<artifactId>QuteeDemoRest</artifactId>
<version>v1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>QuteeDemoRest</name>
```